# I can not find the QWERTZ keyboard layout

Tags: language-support

As the title says i can't get the qwertz german keyboard layout so i can't type some symbols such @ (i copied that symbol)and many more. i've looked in the keyboard layout settings and couldn't find it there.

P.S i m running Ubuntu Latest version alongside Windows 10

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10 or 19.04??

Comment: will German T3 layout help?? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEAAY.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsFC4.png

Comment: Well, the basic German layout is a QUERTZ one. You need to add it from the _Input Sources_ section (the + key).

Comment: All we can do is to manually swap y and z chars,isnt easy but its posible.